# Translate text of mathematical modeling to french

Tags: mathematical-modeling, biology, translation-request

i have the following text concerning modeling and i have difficulties to traslate it in french. Can anyone help me please

The light absorption in a tissue is usually modeled by the Helmholtz equation with two constant parameters, the scattering coefficient and the absorption coefficient. For absorption in the red and in near infrared wavelength range, the man absorber is the haemoglobin present only in blood. So, the absorption coefficient varies and it is equal to zero everywhere exept for a periodic set of thin parallel strips simulating the blood vessels, where it is equal to the large parameter $\omega$. Let $\epsilon$ be the ratio of the distance between the axes of vessels to the characteristic macroscopic size, and let $\delta$ be the ratio of the thickness of thin vessels and the period. Both parameters $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ are supposed to be small. Consider here the simplest one dimensional setting, assuming that the field does not depend on the longitudinal along the vessels. So, below we consider the one-dimensional Helmholtz equation with rapidly oscillating large potential with a periodic support having a small measure of its intersection with the period:
$$
-u''(x)+q(\dfrac{x}{\epsilon}) u(x)= f(x),
$$
with
$$
q(\xi)
=
\begin{cases}
w, & 0<\xi<\dfrac{\delta}{2},\\
0, & \dfrac{\delta}{2} < \xi < 1-\dfrac{\delta}{2},\\
w, & 1-\dfrac{\delta}{2} < \xi < 1,
\end{cases}
$$
$q(\xi)= q(\xi+1)$ for all real $\xi$.

Comment: For the first step (translation to English) I'd propose "man absorber" -> "main absorber".

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand. The text is in english and i want to translate it in french. Can you help me please

Comment: I just wanted to point out an obvious typo, sorry if you don't find that helpful.

Comment: no, it's helpful, i'm sorry.

Comment: As with @JeanMarie, I don't entirely understand what you mean by "periodic support having a small measure of its intersection with the period".   Staring at your $q$ I would, in English, write "... Helmholtz equation with a large potential that is only turned on during periodic short pulses." It is less mathematical but more descriptive.

Comment: Thank you so much. Please, what means here by "assuming that the field does not depend on the longitudinal along the vessels"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La modélisation classique de l'absorption de la lumière dans un tissu utilise l'équation de Helmholtz à deux paramètres, le coefficient de dispersion et le coefficient d'absorption.

En ce qui concerne l'absorption dans le rouge et l'infrarouge proche, l'absorbeur principal est l'hémoglobine contenue dans le sang. Ainsi, le coefficient d'absorption varie et est égal à zero partout sauf le long d'une série périodique de bandes parallèles simulant les vaisseaux sanguins où il est égal à un grand paramètre $\omega$. Soit ϵ le rapport des distances entre les axes des vaisseaux et la taille macroscopique caractéristique, et soit δ le rapport entre l'épaisseur des vaisseaux minces et la période. Les deux paramètres  ϵ et δ sont supposés petits. Considérons ici le plus simple des dispositifs à une dimension, en supposant que le champ ne dépend pas de l'axe longitudinal le long des vaisseaux. Ci-dessous nous considérons l'équation de Helmholtz à une dimension  avec un potentiel important, oscillant rapidement avec un support périodique et dont la mesure d'intersection avec la période (?) est ...

Comment: Thank you so much. Please, what means here by  "assuming that the field does not depend on the longitudinal along the vessels"?

Comment: I assume it means that the field is decreasing in a uniform way as a function of the (shortest) distance to a vessel...

Comment: What means by "field"? Here, and i don't understand "function of the distance to a vessel. And you can explain me in french please

Comment: It means that if 2 points are at the same distance of the vessel, the value of this (scalar) field (=champ in french) is the same.

Comment: But who's the field hear?

Comment: (hear $\to $ here) It's hard to say, as we have only an extract of a certain text. What is the original article ?